# How might I approximate this curve?

Tags: trigonometry, approximation

Hopefully this isn't too vague, but I would like to know an intuitive approach to approximating a function that outlines the negative space of this function (The shapes that resemble parabolas) Something that outlines only the positives value would work, or the negative values. I assume it'll have to be some periodic function, but past that, I can't really think of an intuitive way of determining the curve. [image]

**I edited the picture to make the scale visible (whoops)

Comment: After some trial and error, I found that .5sec(.5π(x±1))+.5 seems to do the trick. I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: That is in line with my answer, given that no scales are provided.The factor $0.5 \pi$ makes the period $4$.

Comment: Secant would seem right to me.

Answer (score 1):

*This is probaly not an answer.*

I do not see why you would like to approximate since there is a closed form

$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p \cos(n\pi x)=\frac{1}{2} \csc \left(\frac{\pi  }{2}x\right) \sin \left(\frac{2 p+1}{2} \pi  
   x\right)+\frac{1}{2}$$

Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225941/proving-sum-limits-k-0n-coskx-frac12-frac-sin-frac2n12x) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151979/sum-of-cosk-x).

Comment: Can I ask where you got that equation? I have no formal education in series, but I would love to know.

Comment: @TomHimler;  ahve look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225941/proving-sum-limits-k-0n-coskx-frac12-frac-sin-frac2n12x

Answer (score 0):

It looks a lot like $y=\pm \sec x$ or $y=\pm \csc x$, which are the same but offset by $\frac \pi 2$.  The values seem to run from something which might be $\pm 1$ to $\pm \infty$ without ever crossing into $(-1,1)$.  The period is something that might be $\pi$ but without a scale we can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)}$$

[image]